# BIND: translate SRV records to A records

Tags: bind, a-record, srv-record

I would like to know if it's possible to configure BIND so that the A record for "sipserver.example.com" points to the A record obtained after performing a SRV query on "_sip._udp.anotherdomain.com".
Basically when I ask for the A record for "sipserver.example.com" I want BIND to make a SRV query for "_sip._udp.anotherdomain.com" to the default DNS server, which will return "sipserver.anotherdomain.com", then make an A query for "sipserver.anotherdomain.com" and finally return the resulting A record.
Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a script that generates both the SRV and the A records based on the given input. That way you will always have matching SRV and A records.

Answer (score 2):

In a word, no. BIND won't do any sort of record translation like this. If you query it for an `A` record it will either serve it authoritatively from its own zones or forward the query to another DNS server and give you the answer. Imagine that the `SRV` record in question has multiple records instead of just one, (which is entirely possible), is BIND supposed to look all of those up?

It sounds like you want a `CNAME` record for `sipserver.example.com` to point at `sipserver.anotherdomain.com` which would give you the end behaviour you're looking for, albeit without involving any intermediate `SRV` records.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not feasible, the address "sipserver.anotherdomain.com" is not known in advance. I don't mind about multiple records, the first one should be fine.

Comment: My point was to generalise the problem; there's no way BIND would just do this just for the first record in the answer set and somehow ignore additional records, that's just not logical behaviour for something critical like DNS. `SRV` records are there to be used by clients for service location, not as logic like this. The behaviour you desire also discards the additional information conveyed in an `SRV` record such as the port and weighting/priority.

Comment: This one shold be marked as the correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

You need change your sipserver.example.com address  record (`A`) to a `CNAME`, try this:

```
sipserver        IN      CNAME  _sip._udp.anotherdomain.com
```

Check the bind documentation [Documentation](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/cname.html)

Comment: That will only  create a pointer, and won't return an `A` response to queries  when there is only a `SRV` but no `A` record for _sip._udp.anotherdomain.com